# Error when updating Project Custom field in AtTask's API

Tags: attask

I am using this URL from within Java code to update a custom field called "ProjectSPI".

```
URL updateProjectUrl = new URL(baseUrl + "proj?updates=" + gson.toJson(fields) + 
    "&method=put&username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password);
```

"fields" is a Map containing:

```
{
    "ID": ProjectID, 
    "DE:ProjectSPI", 
    "1.0"
}
```

This URL works fine for standard fields, but keeps on failing for custom ones.
I read a similar post, but the solution doesn't work for me (at least, I couldn't find what I should use as "categoryID").

Anybody knows what causes the error?

Response code: 400

{"error":{"class":"com.attask.common.InvalidParameterException","message":"category cannot be null","title":null,"msgKey":"exception.attask","attributes":[""],"code":0}}

Comment: It would be useful to see the actual error message.

Comment: I hope this helps to understand what's causing the issue.

Comment: Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason you are getting this error is because the project you are trying to update doesn't have a custom form assigned to it with the field you are trying to update.

I just tested this and I get the exact same error message as you if I try to push a custom field to a (project, task, any object) that doesn't have a custom form with the custom field assigned to it.

Your options are:

1. Either assign a custom form in AtTask
2. In your program first check if a project has the correct custom form assigned. If it doesn't then you could probably add it through the API>

Comment: Thanks a but Craig. Adding the form indeed solved it.